# How to make SNMPv2 queries from Windows 7 to Ubuntu running on VirtualBox

Tags: windows, linux, virtualbox, snmp

I already have snmp installed on Linux and can do queries like snmpwalk, within Linux using command line.

But I have no idea how to do queries from Windows to Linux via the CMD.

My goal is to make a program in java, an SNMP manager, which will query the managed devices. Managed devices are virtual machines running Linux. First I want to make queries through the Windows CMD to check if queries are occurring correctly.

I have already installed the SNMP in Windows and can do SNMP queries via MG-Soft Mib Browser. But don't know hot to send queries to Linux.

Edit: I'm using SNMP4j to make SNMP queries in Java.